# Двумерный массив указателей как поле объекта

Tags: c++, ооп, указатели, динамические-массивы

Есть класс с полем типа двойной указатель. После создания экземпляра класса через указатель, нужно выделить память под двумерный массив указателей данного поля. Набросал пример, но прога виснет. Компилятор ошибок не показывает.

```
    class CBaseData
    {
    public:
      CBaseData(): tag(0) {}
      float **tag;
    };

    int main()
    {
      int tagIndex = 20, num = 5;
      CBaseData* data;

      data->tag = new float*[tagIndex];

      for(int i = 0; i < tagIndex; i++){
        data->tag[i] = new float [num];
      }

      //data->Tag[0][0]= 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        delete[] data->tag[i];
      }

      delete data;
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: На какой строчке виснет-то?

Comment: `delete[] tag;` забыли и `data = new CBaseData;`

Comment: "Двумерный массив указателей"? О чем речь? Я вижу у вас попытку сделать двумерный массив `float`. А где и каким боком здесь "двумерный массив указателей" - не ясно.

Answer (score 3):

Итак,

```
CBaseData* data;
```

Вы объявили указатель на `CBaseData`. Неиницализированный. В нем - какое-то мусорное значение.

После чего по этому мусорному значению не пойми куда указывающему вы начинаете писать:

```
  data->tag = new float*[tagIndex];
```

Дальше пояснять не нужно? :)

Как аналог - вы же не пытаетесь сразу вызывать

```
  for(int i = 0; i < tagIndex; i++){
    data->tag[i] = new float [num];
  }
```

а сперва выделяете для этого память:

```
 data->tag = new float*[tagIndex];
```

Вот так и для `data` тоже неплохо память выделить бы...

А вообще - не стоит лезть внутрь класса снаружи - не для того инкапсуляция придумана... Ошибка не из-за этого, просто это - ну очень плохой стиль...